# Android - Tab #3 is clearing the list view from Tab #1.

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, cursor, kotlin

I have a really odd issue that isn't generating any errors so its extremely hard to troubleshoot (at least for me).

My app has 3 tabs.  Tab 1 has a list view inside a fragment and the other two tabs are basically empty placeholder fragments. When I click on Tab 1 and then Tab 2, then back to Tab 1, my list view remains as expected.  However if I click on Tab 3 then click on Tab 1, my list view disappears. I see no difference between Tab 2 and Tab 3 that would cause this.

I've added the related code from my app.  Please let me know if more is needed.

Any help and advice would be much appreciated!

My Main Activity:

```
var mCursorAdapter: DbCursorAdapter? = null


class CatalogActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


private lateinit var mFragmentPagerAdapter: FragmentPagerAdapter


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mFragmentPagerAdapter = FragmentPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    view_pager_container.adapter = mFragmentPagerAdapter

    view_pager_container.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs))
    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(view_pager_container))

    // Setup FAB to open EditorActivity
    fab_button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@CatalogActivity, EditorActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


    // Kick off the loader
    loaderManager.initLoader(INGREDIENT_LOADER, null, this)
}

/**
 * Helper method to insert hardcoded ingredient data into the database. For debugging purposes only.
 */
private fun insertIngredient() {
    // Create a ContentValues object where column names are the keys,
    // and Rittenhouse Rye Whiskey attributes are the values.
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(IngredientEntry.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_NAME, "Rittenhouse Rye")
    values.put(IngredientEntry.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_DESCRIPTION, "Earthly with a sweet finish.")
    values.put(IngredientEntry.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_CATEGORY, IngredientEntry.CATEGORY_WHISKEY)
    values.put(IngredientEntry.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_WEIGHT, 1)

    // Insert a new row for Rittenhouse Rye Whiskey into the provider using the ContentResolver.
    // Use the {@link IngredientEntry#CONTENT_URI} to indicate that we want to insert
    // into the ingredients database table.
    // Receive the new content URI that will allow us to access Rittenhouse's data in the future.
    contentResolver.insert(IngredientEntry.CONTENT_URI, values)
}

/**
 * Helper method to delete all ingredients in the database.
 */
private fun deleteAllIngredients() {
    val rowsDeleted = contentResolver.delete(IngredientEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, null)
    Log.v("CatalogActivity", rowsDeleted.toString() + " rows deleted from ingredient database")
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu options from the res/menu/menu_catalog.xml file.
    // This adds menu items to the app bar.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_catalog, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
    when (item.itemId) {
    // Respond to a click on the "Insert dummy data" menu option
        R.id.action_insert_dummy_data -> {
            insertIngredient()
            return true
        }
    // Respond to a click on the "Delete all entries" menu option
        R.id.action_delete_all_entries -> {
            deleteAllIngredients()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}


override fun onCreateLoader(i: Int, bundle: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> {
    // Define a projection that specifies the columns from the table we care about.
    val projection = arrayOf(IngredientEntry._ID, IngredientEntry.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_NAME, IngredientEntry.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_DESCRIPTION)

    // This loader will execute the DbContentProvider's query method on a background thread
    return CursorLoader(this, // Parent activity context
            IngredientEntry.CONTENT_URI, // Provider content URI to query
            projection, null, null, null)// Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
    // No selection clause
    // No selection arguments
    // Default sort order
}

override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>, data: Cursor) {
    // Update {@link DbCursorAdapter} with this new cursor containing updated ingredients data
    mCursorAdapter?.swapCursor(data)
}

override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<Cursor>) {
    // Callback called when the data needs to be deleted
    mCursorAdapter?.swapCursor(null)
}

companion object {

    /** Identifier for the ingredients data loader  */
    private val INGREDIENT_LOADER = 0
}
}
```

My Ingredient Fragment:

```
class IngredientsFragment : Fragment() {


override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


}


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ingredient, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // Set empty view on the ListView, so that it only shows when the ingredient_list_view has 0 items.
    ingredient_list_view.emptyView = empty_view

    // Setup an Adapter to create a ingredient_list_view item for each row of ingredient data in the Cursor.
    // There is no ingredient data yet (until the loader finishes) so pass in null for the Cursor.
    mCursorAdapter = DbCursorAdapter(context, null)
    ingredient_list_view.adapter = mCursorAdapter

    // Setup the item click listener
    ingredient_list_view.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _: AdapterView<*>?, _: View?, _: Int, id: Long ->
        // Create new intent to go to {@link EditorActivity}
        val intent = Intent(context, EditorActivity::class.java)

        // Form the content URI that represents the specific ingredient that was clicked on,
        // by appending the "id" (passed as input to this method) onto the
        // {@link IngredientEntry#CONTENT_URI}.
        // For example, the URI would be "content://onCreateDesigns.com.CraftCocktailRecipes.ingredients/ingredients/2"
        // if the ingredient with ID 2 was clicked on.
        val currentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(DbContract.IngredientEntry.CONTENT_URI, id)

        // Set the URI on the data field of the intent
        intent.data = currentUri

        // Launch the {@link EditorActivity} to display the data for the current ingredient.
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}


override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
}


override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
}
}
```

My Adapter:

```
class FragmentPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return when (position) {
        0 -> IngredientsFragment()
        1 -> RecipesFragment()
        else -> FavoritesFragment()

    }
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3
}
}
```

My Ingredient Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="onCreateDesigns.com.CraftCocktailRecipes.IngredientsFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ingredient_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<!-- Empty view for ingredient_list_view list -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/empty_shelter_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_empty_shelter"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty_shelter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/empty_shelter_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/empty_view_title_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_subtitle_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/empty_title_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/empty_view_subtitle_text_ingredients"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#A2AAB0"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I also notice that when I close the app and reopen the listview items on tab 1 vanish. I'm doing something very wrong in regards to lifecycle but I cant seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the default functionality of a **view-pager** that at that time of set Adapter view-pager load **Two Fragments**, when you move fragment 1 to 3 then it will release fragment 1 and wise versa,

if you want to load all of the fragment at the first time than **write** one line after **setAdapter**

```
view_pager_container.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

**setOffscreenPageLimit()** this method load all your three fragments at that time or never initialized again.

Might be helpfull.

Comment: Thank you.  This solved the immediate problem but I feel like I'm still not doing something correctly or as efficiently as I should be.  For example, I've setup tabs before using an ArrayAdapter and listview and never ran into this issue or had to add the code you mentioned for each tab to load normally.

Comment: i dint get it, have you facing some issue?

Answer (score 1):

As interpret your code not added limit of page that should load either side of current page.

[setOffscreenPageLimit(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

You can try this two solution:

1. Just increment value to 2 (i.e `setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`)
2. Add code of list manipulation which set adapter in [`setUserVisibleHint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) method.

Answer (score 0):

In ViewPager, always current, left, and right pages (fragment) are live. whenever you click on Tab 3, the fragment in Tab 1 will be destroyed! When you back to Tab 1, the fragment in Tab 1 will be created again.

Also, i'm not seeing "notifyDataSetChanged()" been called in IngredientsFragment's onViewCreated() fragment. I mean you should load data again from CursorAdapter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Can you please elaborate on what you had in mind using notifyDataSetChanged()?

Answer (score 0):

I advise against loading all at the same time for performance reasons, but if you want to do it I advise you to redefine the getItem() function on  your FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: How would you suggest I refine the getItem() function?  Each fragment will be very different for each tab.  I'm very new to fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i post  this sample on java  but  when copy-paste that on Android Studio this  will be automatically translate on Kotlin language :

```
private class MyDataViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private MyDataViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
  super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
  switch (position) {
    case PAGE_ONE:
      return FragmentOne.newInstance();
    case PAGE_TWO:
      return FragmentTwo.newInstance();
    case PAGE_Three:
    default:
      return FragmentThree.newInstance();
  }
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
  switch (position) {
    case PAGE_ONE:
      return "PAGE_ONE";
    case PAGE_TWO:
      return "PAGE_ONE";
    case PAGE_Three:
    default:
      return "PAGE_ONE";
  }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return TOTAL_PAGE_COUNT;
}


 }
```

inside your  activity :

use that to  link TabLyout and View  pager :

```
 // set adapter
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
tabs.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
```